# "Test with debugger" in ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, resharper, testdriven.net

"TestDriven.NET" has a great feature called "test with debugger". Is there anything like this in ReSharper?

Tried googling this, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper does not have this exact feature. You have to stick with TestDriven.NET for this feature. Or better add full-blown tests to your project, and then you'll be able to run them in debugger (via ReSharper).

Answer (score 8):

If you mean, can you run a test in debug with breakpoints then yes you can do that in ReSharper.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html

Comment: No, I don't mean "running a test". I mean - right-click some random code and selecting "run in debugger". Without any test-frameworks installed.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add, that in VS2012 there's now a built-in feature "Debug selected test". It does exactly the same.

PS. Actually, I (personally found that vs2012 is so good it almost doesn't need Resharper or Productivity-Power-Tools... It's quite good out of the box.. Sorry, just a personal opinion.